# define global namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

How do I define a global namespace, similar to a global variable (via the `extern` keyword)? I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
//header
#ifndef ASD_H
#define ASD_H

namespace Goo
{
    int var;
}
#endif
```

and this header file I would include in all `.cpp` files that would need to access the namespace. This does not work. How is this correctly done?

Comment: "This does not work." <- in what way does it not work???  WTF are you trying to do?

Comment: @BoPersson Absolutely right, that was my question, which is also answered neatly in that very thread. Sorry for my poorly formulated question, can I delete it somehow? It is not worthy of Stackoverflow, but on the other hand I don't want to neglegt your (all 3) contributions. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The default namespace is the global namespace.  Just don't explicitly add a `namespace` in code.

Now that being said, you're asking this because you don't get how namespaces work.  Their job is to clear a scope.  They are not objects.  They do not point to any memory.  They're very "soft" like that.  Any file can declare a namespace, and any classes, structures, functions, etc. that appear in it will be part of that namespace.  Different files don't otherwise need to communicate they're sharing the same namespace; if the text is the same, it's the same namespace.

In reply to your comment:

```
namespace One {
    intvar1;
}

namespace Two {
    int var2;
}
```

Which can then be accessed in other translation units as `One::var1` and `Two::var2`, exactly as if they were not in namespaces and you typed `var1` or `var2` - which means that you are still responsible for declaring `extern` where necessary, etc.

Additionally you can use `namespace Base::One` or `Base::Two` if you have a common base namespace.

Comment: I'm asking because I would like multiple namespaces, e.g. namespace One with var1, namespace Two with var2, etc...

Comment: A perfect answer IMHO